# How to close the drawer screen after navigating from anyone of the screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I need to autoclose the drawer if I have opened the drawer and navigate to some other screens
 I have clicked and opened the drawer and then navigated to other screens via drawer Add button.

Here If I again click on the SAVE button, it comes back to the home screen (With drawer open).

**Actual behaviour:** The drawer is opened in the home screen after I have navigating back via clicking the save button.

**Expected behaviour:** Need to close the drawer while I am navigating back to the homescreen via clicking the save button.

Comment: Can you tell which navigation are you using ? also please share some redirection code

Answer (score 0):

```
1) this.props.navigation.openDrawer()
2) onPress={()=>{this.props.navigateion.navigate('..'),this.props.navigation.closeDrawer()}}
```

this is work for me,

Comment: But it causes the screen transition flickering, because it take twice actions which is not best practice,  first navigate the screen and the close the drawer